# java isDirectory showing wrong result

Tags: java, windows, directory

I have the following code that checks if a file is a directory, and if not, creates it.

```
        File folder = new File(destFolder);
        if (!folder.isDirectory()) {
            if (!folder.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Could not create " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

The code outputs "Could not create " always. I checked and confirmed that the folder with that name already exists. What could be the reason?

If I remove the destFolder, still it is showing the same error. Checked the permissions, I have read, write and execute permissions to the folder. (Weird thing is, it was working till last Friday!)

My machine runs Windows 7, and I am running the code from Netbeans.  Java Platform is - JDK 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get to the mkdir() call if the file is not a directory, in other words if it is a file.  You're trying to run mkdir() against a file.  You should be checking to see if it exists, not if it's a directory.

Comment: ...and to know if (parent.exists()  && parent.isDirectory() && parent.canWrite())

Comment: @JustinC We experience issues with `canWrite` under Java 6 and Windows UAC return false positives - not that you shouldn't use it, but you should beware of it... ;)

Comment: @JustinC : I think that will be the answer to the next question.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, good to know.  I havent touched java for longer than I thought.  It seems that issue might be either fixed, or closely related to this bug# http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7092290  .. is that the crux of the issue?

Comment: @JustinC I don't think it's directly related as we don't get prompted. Basically we call `File#canWrite` which returns `true` so we attempt to write to the location, which (if my memory servers me right) doesn't cause an error, but does not write anything either :P

Comment: @Chris - The folder is created from program. So, its a folder. I will check the parent right now, and will post here

Comment: folder.getParent() - Returns the parent folder which exists when I check from Windows explorer. parent.exists(), parent.isDirectory() and       parent.canWrite() return false. Why does exists() return false for an already existing folder?

Comment: Possibly because of the issue @MadProgrammer hinted at: User Account Control (UAC).  While you may 'see' a file or folder in a file system browser window, you may not have programatic access to it because of file system virtualization, and how your app interacts, or fails to properly interact with a UAC system (notably Vista/7).  Is the 'parent' directory in question part of a 'special' directory structure (eg Program Files, My Documents, etc)?

Comment: The folder structure is like C:/Users/myUser/Projects/..../tempfolder . The weird thing is, as I mentioned in the question, this was working till last Friday. Not sure, if its me, or any Java update or any windows update which is causing the issue